# $limit and $count not working when using $seach & $match together - Atlas Search

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongodb-atlas-search

```
let pipeline = [
    {
        $search: {
            index: indexes.CAREERS_SEARCH_INDEX,
            compound: {
                should: [
                    {
                        autocomplete: {
                            query: searchText,
                            path: 'role_title',
                            fuzzy: {
                                maxEdits: 1,
                            },
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        autocomplete: {
                            query: searchText,
                            path: 'industry',
                            fuzzy: {
                                maxEdits: 1,
                            },
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        autocomplete: {
                            query: searchText,
                            path: 'overview',
                            fuzzy: {
                                maxEdits: 1,
                            },
                        }
                    },
                ],
            },
        },
    },
];

if (industries && industries.length) {
    pipeline.push({
        $match: { industry: { $in: industries } },
    });
}

pipeline.push({
    $limit: limit
});

pipeline.push({
    $group: {
        _id: null,
        search_results: { $push: "$$ROOT" },
        matched_count: { $sum: 1 }
    }
});

pipeline.push({
    $project: {
        _id: 0,
        search_results: 1,
        matched_count: 1
    }
});

let results = await CareerModel.aggregate(pipeline);
results = results[0];
data.careers = results.search_results;
data.count = results.matched_count;
return data;
```

If the results are `40` then limiting the results to `10` changes the `matched_count` to `10` as well when it should be `40` actually. The mongoose documentation on atlas search is very limited and does not cover cases like these. If you have faced a similar issue, it would be great if you can just point me in the right direction. Thanks!